# Why does scanf matches different string ends

Tags: c, scanf

Why does this matches both cases ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void) {
    int n; char S[256];
    n=sscanf("A_BB_CCC_123.YES", "%[^.].YES", S);
    printf("n:%d, %s\n", n, S);

    *S='\0';
    n=sscanf("A_BB_CCC_123.NO", "%[^.].YES", S);
    printf("n:%d, %s\n", n, S);
}

$ gcc tscanf.c && ./a.out 
n:1, A_BB_CCC_123
n:1, A_BB_CCC_123
```

Shouldn't it be n:0 in the second case ? And if it matches the S up to the '.' and then ignores the rest, how can I discriminate between the endings ?

Comment: Declare `main` with an `int` return type, not `void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sscanf` returns the number of input items that it assigned (except that, if an input failure occurs before the first conversion completes, it returns `EOF`). In `sscanf("A_BB_CCC_123.NO", "%[^.].YES", S);`, “A_BB_CCC_123” matches and is assigned to `S`. Then “.” matches. Then “YES” does not match “NO”, so `sscanf` stops and returns the number of items it assigned, which is one.

If you want to know whether matching reached the end of the string, you can use `%n` at the end to request a count of the number of input characters consumed. If it changes from what you initialize the count to, then `sscanf` reached the end:

```
    int characters = -1;
    n = sscanf("A_BB_CCC_123.NO", "%[^.].YES%n", S, &characters);
    if (n == 1)
        if (characters != -1)
            printf("Matched all the way to the end.\n");
        else
            printf("Matched partly.\n");
    else
        printf("Did not match anything.\n");
```

(An assignment with `%n` is not included in the assignment count that `sscanf` returns; it will still return just 1, for the `%[` conversion.)

Comment: That's somewhat convoluted, but that'll do ! Thanks